# Operation ignoring via pointers in AVL tree

Tags: c

I am building an AVL tree, using this structure:

```
typedef struct node* nodep;
typedef struct node {
    int postal_number;
    int h; /* height */
    nodep left, right, parent;
} Node;
```

Everything is working great: rotating, searching and inserting. The problem is with deleting a node. It deletes most of the node, except for few leaves after deleting most of the tree. My delete code (the problematic part) is:

```
int delete_postal(nodep* t, int in_postal){
    nodep to_delete;
    nodep* the_parent;

    to_delete = search_postal((*t), in_postal);
    the_parent = &(to_delete->parent);

    /** if the node we want to delete is a leave **/

    if (to_delete->right == NULL && to_delete->left == NULL) {
        if (to_delete == (*the_parent)->right){ /* the node we want to delete is right son */
            (*the_parent)->right = to_delete->right;
        else { /* the node we want to delete is left son */
            (*the_parent)->left = to_delete->left;
    }
```

I made it so `(*the_parent)` will be the node himself in the tree, and when debugging it stepping into the `if`, it acts as if it did the deletion (making the child of the node the child of the node's father - I'm not dealing with `malloc` right now), but it just does not do it. The father keeps on pointing to the node that I would like to delete and not to NULL.

All the rest of the first deletion (nodes and leaves) works fine with this syntax.

Does somebody know what I am missing?

Comment: `the_parent = &(to_delete->parent);` does the root node have a parent?

Comment: Why you make `the_parent` a pointer to `nodep`? It seems to be unnecessary in your code

Comment: The father of the root node is NULL. The leave i try to delete have a father. The father's right child or the left child just don't become NULL.

Comment: And you right, it is not neccessery. It didn't work even when he was just nodep.